# ITK itkImageFileReader.h causing linking errors

Tags: c++, cmake, qt-creator, itk, msvc12

I have built ITK 4.10 with CMAKE and Visual Studio 2013 but I work with it on QtCreator. I have followed this link [to write the .pro file](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/community/2014-March/005494.html). It works great except for one point. When I include itkImageFileReader.h, I get 11 LNK2019 errors (others .h files cause no problem).
Here some of the rapscallions:

```
itksys-4.10.lib(SystemTools.obj):-1: erreur : LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_OpenProcessToken referenced in function "bool __cdecl itksys::DeleteJunction(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (?DeleteJunction@itksys@@YA_NAEBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)

itksys-4.10.lib(SystemTools.obj):-1: erreur : LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_AdjustTokenPrivileges referenced in function "bool __cdecl itksys::DeleteJunction(class std::basic_string<wchar_t,struct std::char_traits<wchar_t>,class std::allocator<wchar_t> > const &)" (?DeleteJunction@itksys@@YA_NAEBV?$basic_string@_WU?$char_traits@_W@std@@V?$allocator@_W@2@@std@@@Z)

itksys-4.10.lib(EncodingCXX.obj):-1: erreur : LNK2019: unresolved external symbol __imp_CommandLineToArgvW referenced in function "public: static class itksys::Encoding::CommandLineArguments __cdecl itksys::Encoding::CommandLineArguments::Main(int,char const * const *)" (?Main@CommandLineArguments@Encoding@itksys@@SA?AV123@HPEBQEBD@Z)
```

It can't find itksys-4.10.lib(SystemTools.obj) and (EncodingCXX.obj).

Here is the .pro file:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11
TARGET = itkTest

CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

INCLUDEPATH += C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/include/ITK-4.10

LIBS += -LC:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release
LIBS += "C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKBiasCorrection-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKBioCell-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKCommon-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKDICOMParser-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkdouble-conversion-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKEXPAT-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKFEM-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkgdcmcharls-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkgdcmCommon-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkgdcmDICT-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkgdcmDSED-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkgdcmIOD-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkgdcmjpeg8-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkgdcmjpeg12-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkgdcmjpeg16-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkgdcmMEXD-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkgdcmMSFF-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkgdcmopenjpeg-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkgdcmsocketxx-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKgiftiio-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkhdf5_cpp-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkhdf5-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOBioRad-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOBMP-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOCSV-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOGDCM-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOGE-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOGIPL-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOHDF5-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOImageBase-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOIPL-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOJPEG-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOLSM-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOMesh-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOMeta-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOMRC-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIONIFTI-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIONRRD-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOPNG-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOSiemens-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOSpatialObjects-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOStimulate-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOTIFF-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOTransformBase-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOTransformHDF5-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOTransformInsightLegacy-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOTransformMatlab-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOVTK-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKIOXML-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkjpeg-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKKLMRegionGrowing-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKLabelMap-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKMesh-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKMetaIO-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itknetlib-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkNetlibSlatec-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKniftiio-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKNrrdIO-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKOptimizers-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKOptimizersv4-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKPath-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkpng-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKPolynomials-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKQuadEdgeMesh-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKSpatialObjects-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKStatistics-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itksys-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itktestlib-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itktiff-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKTransform-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkv3p_netlib-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkvcl-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKVideoCore-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKVideoIO-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkvnl_algo-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkvnl-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKVNLInstantiation-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKVTK-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKWatersheds-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/itkzlib-4.10.lib" \
"C:/InsightToolkit-4.10.0/build/lib/Release/ITKznz-4.10.lib"

SOURCES += main.cpp
```

I tried a rebuild but nothing changed.
Do you have an idea to fix that ?

Thanks !

John

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problems for a build with a custom visual studio project. Some Windows standard libraries are missing. For the *itkImageFileReader*, you need *Advapi32.lib* and *Shell32.lib*.

In my visual studio project, *inherit from parent or project defaults* was not checked in Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.

Comment: This answer is also applicable to my case [ITK 4.10, VC++ 2015, building 64-bit application in release mode, Windows 10 64 bit].